# How to HTML escape strings from the server in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on a large legacy Ruby on Rails app that has no script injection protection *(e.g. you can type `<script>console.log('hackd')<script>` into a person's address, save it, and the code will run when loading the page).*

The app also inserts some custom HTML tags into our template rendering. We thus can't use the escape function `<%-` in our EJS templates because we need to show this HTML.

So I thought the best place to escape our data is when it arrives on the browser from the server, like so:

```
  Backbone.Model.prototype.parse = function(resp, options) {
    return escapeStringsRecursively(resp);
  }

  function escapeStringsRecursively(o) { //https://github.com/wesleytodd/recursive-escape/blob/master/index.js
    if (typeof o === 'undefined' || o === null)
      return o;
    if (o instanceof Array)
      for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        o[i] = escapeStringsRecursively(o[i]); }
    else if (typeof o === 'object')
      for (var i in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(i))
          o[i] = escapeStringsRecursively(o[i]); }
    else if (typeof o === 'string')
      o = _.escape(o);
    return o;
  }
```

- **Is the best place to do it in Backbone?**
- Strings are correctly escaped now  when I first load a page - but if I navigate to a new page then press the browser's back button, or navigate to the page a second time, the data isn't escaped anymore, and the script runs.  **Why is this? How do I fix it?**

Below's a .gif of what is happening.

When I first load the page you can see my parse method catches strings with `script` in them and escapes them to the screen with nice HTML. Then I navigate to another page and return. Now the method never fires, the page is broken, and the script tags have run console.errors:

[image]

Comment: _Is the best place to do it in Backbone?_ The answer is **no**. The data should be sanitized before being saved on the server. Then, it wouldn't even be a question when receiving data from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot do that at this stage. That would require hundreds of changes to the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also added parse on `Backbone.Collection.prototype.parse` in addition to `Backbone.Model.prototype.parse` because we found that Model was called only on the first page load, but Collection was called on all page loads.

We then had to change our escape code avoid to double escaping: `o = _.escape(_.unescape(o));` because Collection and Model would double escape it the first time.

We don't know why the Model.parse wasn't called on subsequent Backbone.fetches but this workaround is ok.